# How to override the last line with tail?

Tags: perl, newline, tail

To monitor a log file I use the following command:

`tail -f -n 1 myfile.log | perl -ne 'print if s/progress (\d+).*/$1%/g'`

This will create lines with a a number in my terminal. How can I modify this command to overwrite the last line? Adding `\r\033[K` doesn't do the trick:

`` tail -f -n 1 myfile.log | perl -ne 'print if s/progress (\d+).*/`\r\033[K$1%/g' ``

Comment: What does the "last line" mean if you're running `tail -f`?

Comment: My command generates output like this: 56 (newline) 57 (newline) 58 (newline) 59 ... and I want to see the last number only. In that case 59.

Comment: Yes. But `tail -f` keeps running, and doesn't send an `eof` - so `perl` can't know when it _is_ the "last line" because there might be another one coming.

Comment: ... otherwise you could do `if eof`

Comment: @LarsSchneider do you mean to show only the latest line from `tail -f` always?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you read a line in Perl, the trailing new-line character is not stripped. Also, a `.` in a regex does not match the new-line character unless the `s` modifier is present. Thus, in your second snippet, the `\r` character is always printed as the first character in a line and hence does not have any effect.

To fix it, the following can be done:

1. Add the `s` modifier in the regex to remove the new-line character as well.
2. Before printing the string, print a `\r` character to move to the first position in the line.
3. Since `STDOUT` is line-buffered, you need to change it to auto-flush every time something is printed. This can be done by assigning `1` to `$|`.

Final code:

```
perl -ne '$|=1; print if s/progress (\d+).*/\r$1%/s'
```